Value range of dual variables in Jonker-Volgenant algorithm for solving linear assignment problem
In A shortest augmenting path algorithm for dense and sparse linear assignment problems an algorithm for the Linear Assignment Problem is given, with a $O(N^3)$ time complexity (where $N$ is the "size" of the problem).
Available implementations are not generic enough (in terms of supported data types) and I have to rewrite them. Indeed, I want to be able to support all standard type for the problem costs (floating points, signed or unsigned integral types).
The issue is that the computation of some variables can overflow:

the "dual variables" (especially the one called $v$ in the paper);
the distance $d$ (which is a distance for a modified Djikstra algorithm)

I'd like to have the tightest possible bounds on these variables, with respect to the range of the assignment costs and the problem size (as I suspect they are all the meaningful parameters).
Besides, these range may depend on the number of iterations inside the "augmenting row reduction" stage. I'd like to know if there is a bound on the number of iteration inside the while block (it scan repeatedly unassigned "workers" and, during this step a "worker" can potentially oscillate between assigned and unassigned status). During extensive testing with floating point costs, I observed infinite loop situation and I don't know if they are a consequence of the implementation (finite precision of real numbers) or a property of the algorithm. By the way, a matlab implementation introduces a "hack" that experimentally work but for which I have no theoretical justification.
I'm posting on a math forum and not a coding one because, IMHO, it's a mathematical problem as, if the bounds exists, I think that they will come from graph theory and not from implementation considerations.
